# How can I get facebook user detail using email in c#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, c#-4.0

I have list of user emails and I need to get details from facebook using that email id in c#. I have used graph search api which only returns name and Id against searched name. 
I need to get public details which is a legal request and I believe there is a way to get it however its unknown to me. 
I would highly appreciate your response.

Looking forward.
Sohaib

Comment: There is no way to get user information using Graph API, just because you have their email address.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get Facebook profiles by email. You only get user details i you authorize the user with your App - you can authorize him with the `email` permission to match the email to a profile.

Just because data is public on facebook.com does not mean you can get it with the Graph API. It also does not mean you can do anything with the data, you always need approval of the user.

Comment: how about accessing my own facebook  information from winforms desktop application using search api ? and is there a way to prevent token expiry so that I can use it for good

Comment: i am not sure how that is related to this thread, to be honest. you get data by using the graph api and after authorizing the user.